# Trying to install react-native-google-nearby-messages

Tags: react-native, npm

I keep getting an error when trying to react-native-google-nearby-messages for react native and I don't know why I keep getting it.

[image: Error]

I tried googling errors but unfortunately this isn't a very common package.

Comment: Have you installed the library through yarn?

Comment: Unfortunately the library is quite outdated and I don't think you can install it.